# Range Between Two Dates

Tags: sql-server

Given three separate date fields:

COMPLETION_DATE: 4/27/2017
DUE_DATE:  7/22/2016
LATEST_DATE: 7/20/2018

Use DATEDIFF(MM,DUE_DATE,LATEST_DATE), I can calculate the result as 24.

I then need to be able to figure out (in months) where the completion date falls within that range. The result should be 21.

Comment: Oops, the result should be 21 instead of 19.

Comment: What did you try?   What error did you get?

Comment: I haven't tried anything other than the first formula. I can't figure out how to proceed with the second piece.

Comment: What method do you use to come up with 21 from those dates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miscalculated the result, or made a typo when providing the dates. If the `completion_date` was `2018-04-27` instead of the `2017-04-27` you have in your question, then the result would be `21`.

```
create table t (completion_date date, due_date date, latest_date date);
insert into t values ('20180427','20160722','20180720');

select 
    completion_date = convert(char(7),completion_date)
  , due_date = convert(char(7),due_date)
  , latest_date = convert(char(7),latest_date)
  , months_for_completion = datediff(month,due_date,latest_date)
  , months_until_completion = datediff(month,due_date,completion_date)
  , months_remaining_at_completion = datediff(month,completion_date,latest_date)
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DEV75985

returns:

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
| completion_date | due_date | latest_date | months_for_completion | months_until_completion | months_remaining_at_completion |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2018-04         | 2016-07  | 2018-07     |                    24 |                      21 |                              3 |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: The months remaining at completion number is correct. The person who provided me values gave me incorrect information. Go figure.